# tmhOauth twitter api stopped working with update_with_media call

Tags: twitter

So, this morning I got the following error:

```
{"errors": [{"message": "The Twitter REST API v1 will soon stop functioning. 
Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.",
"code": 68}]}
```

Since I was using the [tmhOauth twitter api](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) I went to look if there are updates for it, and as it seems there is an issue listed [here](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/issues/132).

I'm using the api to update the status with media like this:

```
$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
        array(
            'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
            'status'   => "{$text}"
        ),
        true, // use auth
        true  // multipart
);
```

I found notes that I should just change the link to use `1.1` instead of `1` but it's still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My main problem was that I didn't read the docs fully! While the change in the url from `1` to `1.1` was sufficient I missed the point by not looking that the new url for update_with_media, 
as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update_with_media), is `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json`, namely it's **api** instead of the old **upload** subdomain.

So, now my api call looks like this and all works again:

```
$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
        array(
            'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
            'status'   => "{$text}"
        ),
        true, // use auth
        true  // multipart
    );
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: is the $image imageurl?

Comment: @Tahtakafa: yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using tmhOauth api, use abraham's twitteroauth api ( updated to version 1.1 ) :

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master/twitteroauth

and replace your code as follows :

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($twitter_consumer_key, $twitter_consumer_secret, $twAccessToken, $twAccessTokenSecret);

$parameters = array(
            'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
            'status'   => "{$text}"
        );
$code = $connection->post('statuses/update_with_media', $parameters);
```